# Cannot kill process by pg_terminate_backend

Tags: postgresql

I face strange situation that i have some active queries most probably coming from `Power BI` (uses regular postgres user) against my Postgres database which I am not able to kill at all.

I use to use `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` which normally always works, nevertheless seems like for some reason I am not able to kill such queries running which are growing (`max_connections`) is reached in some time and db is down.

Can anyone explains me why `pg_terminate_backend()` executed by `postgres` user cannot kill such queries? This should work. Is there any other way i can get rid of running `pids`?

As a workaround i am restarting database but it's just workaround and this situation happens again and again.

**EDIT:**

```
    ps:

    bash-4.4# /bin/ps -o pid,ppid,rss,vsz,stat,args
PID   PPID  RSS  VSZ  STAT COMMAND
    1     0  12m 194m S    pg-operator leader_election --enable-analytics=true --logtostderr=true --alsologtostderr=false --v=3 --stderrthreshold=0
   33     1 417m  18g S    postgres
   38     1    0    0 Z    [postgres]
 9494    33 1.1g  18g S    postgres: checkpointer   
 9495    33 4.0g  18g S    postgres: background writer   
 9496    33  19m  18g S    postgres: walwriter   
 9497    33 5264  18g S    postgres: autovacuum launcher   
 9498    33 2084  44m S    postgres: archiver   last was 00000001000005140000002A
 9499    33 2772  45m S    postgres: stats collector   
 9500    33  22m  18g S    postgres: pg_cron scheduler   
 9501    33 3468  18g S    postgres: logical replication launcher   
 9730    33  29m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(21438) idle
10946    33  27m  18g S    postgres: postgres bia 10.42.85.0(38501) idle
10947    33  43m  18g S    postgres: postgres bia 10.42.85.0(1971) idle
10965    33  14g  18g D    postgres: postgres bia 10.42.85.0(53728) CALL
11536    33  33m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(12117) idle
12768    33 121m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(28184) idle
12814    33 227m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(55887) idle
12815    33 243m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(19257) idle
12853    33 191m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(6347) idle
12875    33 286m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(42531) idle
12876    33  64m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(33504) idle
12891    33 794m  18g S    postgres: sinder bia 10.42.85.0(34256) idle
13196     0 1632 2420 S    bash
13380    33 137m  18g R    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13381    33 137m  18g R    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13382    33 138m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13383    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13384    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13385    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13386    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13387    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13388    33 137m  18g D    postgres: parallel worker for PID 10965   
13535 13196   16 1536 R    /bin/ps -o pid,ppid,rss,vsz,stat,args
```

Comment: Please add the process number of a backend that cannot be killed and the output of `ps -u postgres -o pid,ppid,s,args`. A look at the `pg_stat_activity` view would also help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i am using pg_stat_activity and seeing this process/-s

Comment: Yes, and what is their `state`, `wait_event_type` and `wait_event`? It would help if you could add all that to the question (by [edit]ing it). Don't forget the `ps` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  For most of them state is 'active', wait_event_type is 'IPC' (maybe one is 'CLient'). Looks like it's same query which in time is creating new PIDs. Why the heck pg_terminate_backedn cannot kill it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i also inserted output from ps. This 'sinder' user process's are the processes i cannot kill in any way.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe For most of them active PIDs are marked as IPC and for idle are Client event types. This is shown on pg_stat_activity

Comment: You forgot the important `S` in the `-o` option of `ps`. It would also be interesting to see `pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe s cannot be used seems like not available when using that command

Comment: Then that is a more exotic operating system. Figure out how to get the process state.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it might be STAT- take a look i updated post

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I'm still missing `pg_stat_activity` though.

Comment: Which pids (from your ps output) have you tried and failed to kill?  Do you get any warnings or errors?  What happens if you try to kill it from the OS command line with `kill`?

Comment: @jjanes never tried to kill them using kill from OS. When running from postgres by pg_terminate_backend(pid) i just receive true but processes remains in PIDs